# Am not able to print from a simple sql statement to query mssql db

Tags: php, sql-server

I am doing a simple select from a mssql db.

```
$sql = "select * from dbo.table where [xxx] ='".$_POST['xx']."' AND [yyy]='".$_POST['yy']."'";
  $StmtUser = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql );
```

And when I am echo-ing it does not print result

```
echo $StmtUser['xxx'];


$serverName = "usr\SQLEXPRESS"; 
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"dbname", "UID"=>"x12", "PWD"=>"123");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
```

How do I get to print `echo $StmtUser['xxx'];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`sqlsrv_query()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-query.php) returns a statement resource so you need to use [`sqlsrv_fetch_array()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-fetch-array.php) before you can access any values.

```
...
$ResultUser = sqlsrv_fetch_array($StmtUser);
echo $ResultUser['xxx'];
```